# Retrieving the Value of an input text field in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Absolute noob question.

I have a form

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="cars" name="cars"/>
</form>
```

When the user clicks on a link , my jquery function needs to pick up the current value of this input field.

How do I retrieve this value? Doing a $("#cars").val gives me a block of html and not the string typed in by the user, Also $("cars").text throws a null value.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're calling it as a function (with parenthesis!), `$("#cars").val()` will give you want you want here.

For example:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    alert($("#cars").val());
});​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/qTWk4/), without the parenthesis you're getting the *function*, not executing it and getting the *result*, [see what I mean in a demo of that here](http://jsfiddle.net/qTWk4/1/).

Comment: @b_ayan - It's just a handy tool a few of the mootools put together, there are a few out there, but I personally prefer it to jsbin and such :)

Answer (score 0):

var carValue =  $("#cars").val();

carValue will give you current value.